'ssr' does not exist in type 'ResourcesConfig | LegacyConfig | AmplifyOutputs'.ts(2353)
I am following a tutorial - ref point is 2:25:16 - on making a full stack application, however, I got stuck at enabling SSR.
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";

// AWS imports
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import awsExports from '../src/aws-exports';

Amplify.configure({...awsExports, ssr: true});

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

The error I'm getting:

"Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'ssr' does not exist in type 'ResourcesConfig | LegacyConfig | AmplifyOutputs'.ts(2353)"

Not sure how I should fix this. I even tried this, where I import outputs: import outputs from '@/amplify_outputs.json', but that didn't work as the file does not exist.
What should I do to fix it?

To just ignore the error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'ssr' does not exist in type 'ResourcesConfig | LegacyConfig | AmplifyOutputs'.ts(2353), and make it stop, you can define the src as a any type, it would look something similar to this:
Amplify.configure({...awsExports, ssr: true} as any);

This will stop the property error, but you will ignore the configuration types, however you can extend the configuration properties, which may solve your problem.
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import awsExports from '../src/aws-exports';

const newAwsExports = {...awsExports, ssr: true}; //Create as a variable(example variable name) 

Amplify.configure(newAwsExports) //Use Amplify.configure with new variable

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

